# Where is the correct place to put socket.io connection in Node.js backend?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs("mongodb://USER:PASS@SERVER:PORT/DB", []);
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var request = require('request');
var fcm = require('./routes/fcm');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));

require('./routes/sockets')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm);
require('./routes/userServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm);
require('./routes/ridesServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request);
require('./routes/offersServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request);
require('./routes/notificationsServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request);

server.listen("8080", function() {
  console.log("Connected to db and listening on port 8080");
});
```

As you can see, I define the main modules in the app.js file and then I transfer it as a "dependency" to each route page.

As this I have the /routes/sockets.js page, which I thought that will be smart to put there the socket.io connection and handle each actions emitted from clients, like this:

/routes/sockets.js file:

```
module.exports = function(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request) {

  io.on('connection', function(socket){

    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on("To server", function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });

  });

};
```

There (routes/sockets.js) I can handle actions comming from client's side like this:

```
socket.emit("To server", "The Data");
```

Does it a correct place to place it?
Am I doing okay or it should be corrected?

Thanks.

Comment: i just create a gist for you https://gist.github.com/shivshankar3578/2c863c008afdb45746d82b370dec4846 go through and give your feedback. your feedback will be appreciated

Comment: That is good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make a new file with a function that takes the `io` object and spits out all `socket` directives, like this

My sample app/server/index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require("http");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
const socketHolder = require("./utils/sockets"); // this is the file I put my sockets in
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketio(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    allowedHeaders: "*",
  },
});

const connectDB = require("./config/db");

socketHolder(io);

// Database connection
connectDB()

// ... additional router stuff
```

My *socketHolder* util file

```js
// All requires at the top of the file

const socketHolder = (io) => 
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("doSomething", () => {
      console.log("Do something")
    })
    // ...etc
  })
```